# Is it possible to rename pets in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have the Demented Elytra Nymph from the [Saints and Seducers](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Saints_%26_Seducers) quest, and I'd like to rename them. The name's really long in my favorited spells, which is a little annoying. Plus I just want to give them a name. I'm playing on Nintendo Switch, so unfortunately I can't use commands. Can anyone help, or at least confirm whether or not you can rename pets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you can't without the use of console commands or using a mod. So even if you adopted the dog for example it wil remain as "Stray dog" which in my opinion is a development oversight that should have been addressed in the anniversary edition.